# Can an arbitrary quantum system of finite size be made to reliably relax to its ground state? Is there a physical principle prohibiting this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, ground-state, open-quantum-systems

I am talking about the possibility of reliably cooling an arbitrary quantum system of FINITE size (for example, localized on earth), to its ground state through any means, like exposure to a special kind of environment etc. By reliable, I mean that for the given system, can we calculate a finite time T after which it has a high probability, lets say 75%, of relaxing to the ground state?

Can this always be done? If not, is there a physical argument prohibiting it?

More Details for context: I read a [paper][1] that gives a physical argument why this may not be possible. It asserts that the ground state of carbon is known to be graphite, yet tiny pieces of diamond have been found to survive in meteorites for billions of years.

I tried to set up the GKSL equation for the relaxation of a two state system exposed to some environment at temperature T. I found that a quantum cooling analogous to newton cooling in the sense that there are exponential decay terms for the off diagonal elements and so on, can be incorporated as the lindblad equation.

So the catch may be that the system may get caught somewhere in a local minima for an indefinite amount of time, prohibiting it from reaching the ground state.

[1]: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.6029&rep=rep1&type=pdf “ Smith, Warren D. "Three counterexamples refuting Kieu’s plan for “quantum adiabatic hypercomputation”; and some uncomputable quantum mechanical tasks." Applied Mathematics and Computation 178.1 (2006): 184-193.”

Note: to get to the relevant paragraph of the paper above, search for the term 'cool' in the pdf.

Comment: I would like to ask for clarification on what the question is here. Is your interest in *cooling techniques* and if they can practically achieve 75% ground state probability? Or are you asking the *theoretical question* if there are (open? driven?) quantum systems which do not relax to the ground state? In both cases the answer is a simple yes, but I think the question needs to be clearly outlined here.

Comment: @Wolpertinger My question is, are there cooling techniques which can practically achieve 75% ground state probability for a finite calculable runtime T? I am not concerned whether T is 100 years or longer. What concerns me though is that T should be finite and can be determined for all systems in question. I don’t understand what you mean with- there are quantum systems that do not relax to ground state. Do you mean to say that there are quantum systems on which no such cooling technique can be applied?

Comment: Since you said *My question is, are there cooling techniques which can practically achieve 75% ground state probability for a finite calculable runtime T?* you seem to be asking the practical question. That's fair, but for which system? If you're asking for *any* system: no, you can't cool the universe (sorry for the absurd example, just to show why the question is unclear). If you're asking for a particular system, some specification is required.

Comment: The theoretical question I suggested would be well defined in my opinion and I thought you might be asking it based on the sentence *"So the catch may be that the system may get caught somewhere in a local minima for an indefinite amount of time, prohibiting it from reaching the ground state."* The answer to this question is yes, there are fancy things like time crystals in dissipative systems where this can happen. But this is not a question of whether you *can* cool something practically.

Comment: @Wolpertinger About the universe being a system that cannot be cooled, the universe, by definition, is all there is. So, it cannot be acted upon from outside, because there is no outside. So I would like to reframe my question- For a quantum system of FINITE size (for example, localized on earth), are there cooling techniques which can practically achieve 75% ground state probability for a finite calculable runtime T? Thanks for helping in making my question precise.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I appreciate the attempt for improvement. However, I don't think the addition of the word "finite" resolves the problem. There are multiple quesitons here and they are not clearly separated. Either way, I've voiced my criticism and registered a close vote, so let's let the community decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in principle at least. A number of points

1. Cooling down corresponds to a time-evolution in *imaginary* time $\tau$ i.e. $\hat{\rho}(t)=e^{-\hat{H}\tau}\hat{\rho}_0 e^{-\hat{H}\tau}$, and it is easy to see that this leads to the ground state.
2. The whole notion of cooling down relies on the Second Law of Thermodynamics: basically, any (equilibrium) system will tend towards a Boltzmann-Gibbs state at infinite time, and the corresponding temperature will go to the one of its environment. So if you put the system in a $T=0$ bath, eventually it goes to its ground state. The assumption is here that thermodynamics is valid, meaning we are relying on ergodicity (for any microstate, there exist *some* incoherent process connecting it to the other microstates), but this is widely accepted except for some very specifically engineered cases. Thermodynamics doesn't tell anything about the timescales involved, though.
3. Consider as a practical setup, that the system couples with empty space, a bath at $T=0$. Cooling down occurs by spontaneous emission, single-photon losses in the simplest case. We can describe this process with a Lindblad equation, and an associated *Liouvillian superoperator* $\mathcal{L}$. In case where where the quantum-dynamical semigroup is irreducible (basically, this is the same assumption as ergodicity), $\mathcal{L}$ has a unique lowest eigenvector, the *steady state* (also known as *Spohn's theorem*). If the emission process can only decrease energy, the *steady state* is the same as the ground state. The spectrum of $\mathcal{L}$ has also a gap, and the inverse of this *Liouvillian gap* corresponds to the slowest timescale associated with cooling.

Of course, *meta*stabilities exist, but that's what they are, metastable so at some point, possibly longer than the age of the universe, the system will decay further. A good example of long-living metastabilities are glasses. Typically, slow cooling or thermal *annealing* where the temperature is decreased slowly, overcomes metastabilities faster than connecting it to a $T=0$ bath as described above.

Comment: *"[...] the decay rate to the ground state, which is also the steady state of the Liouvillian superoperator [...]"* $\rightarrow$ This is not true for general Liouvillians and also not within the assumptions stated in this answer. Example: the steady-state of a two-level atom coupled to a finite temperature bath is not its ground state. -1 for now.

Comment: Thanks @Wolpertinger for your remark. What you say is absolutely true, of course. However, I was specifically talking about empty space as in 'without photons'  and this is equivalent to T=0. In fact the second law of thermodynamics should be a sufficient argument why cooling is possible, but it doesn't tell anything about the dynamics of cooling (which is also what the question is about). Perhaps, I can clarify my answer.

Comment: great, I agree and will be happy to change the vote upon clarification

Comment: @Wolpertinger done